# Какие файлы должны быть в релизной сборке?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Добрый день!

Похоже я достиг нового этапа в становлении программистом, когда зашел в папку с одной из разработанных программ, и стал немыслимо негодовать с криками "Что за хрень?!!".

Всем нам, еще с тех времен, когда игры качали с торрентов, а для активации и взлома игры нужно было файлы из папки "Crack" поместить в папку с игрой, знакома картина, как должны выглядеть внутренности софта. В этих папках все хорошо структурировано: несколько папок с библиотеками и ресурсами и сам ярлык игры.

Так вот захожу я в папку с своей программой для того, чтобы сделать установочный файл, а там куча ненужной информации.

Сразу хочу сказать, я искал и гуглил информацию по вопросам, которые описаны ниже, но многие темы которые могли бы мне помочь созданы давно и скорей всего люди отвечавшие там не смогут мне быстро дать дополнительные разъяснения.

Буду благодарен любой информации, как личному объяснению, так и ссылкам на умную и нудную документацию.

Программирую на C#, использую для этого Visual Studio 2015 и Visual Studio 2017.

Сами вопросы:

1. Как разложить библиотеки и файлы программы по соответствующим папкам?
   Нашел способ с прописыванием в файл с конфигурацией, но неужели это единственный способ? Уверен есть куда более изысканный и красивый способ это сделать!
2. Зачем нужны файлы .pdb в релизной сборке и возможно ли от них избавиться? И если возможно то как?
3. Нужны ли файлы .xml в релизной сборке? И если не нужны, то как от них избавиться?

P.s. Файлы .vshost.ext и manifest я догадался как отключить и их назначение знаю))

Всем спасибо за потраченное время и помощь!

Comment: Слишком много у вас воды, можно спокойно вырезать все приветы и предисловия. 1. Универсального способа нет. 2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5457250/5752652 3. Какие конкретно?

Comment: @AK , понедельник день тяжелый) уставшему и голодному прогеру захотелось выговориться)
Я имел ввиду .xml файлы сторонних библиотек, которые использую в проекте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В типовом проекте студия сама автоматически сложит все файлы в
   каталоге out/release как нужно. Наводить порядок вручную не стоит:
   на это тратится время, а смысла особого в наведении порядка ради
   порядка нет.

   Если вам всё же нужно что-то нестандартное... Откройте Рихтер CLR
   via C#, Глава 2 Компоновка, упаковка, развертывание и
   администрирование    приложений и типов, "Алгоритм поиска файлов
   сборки", там есть краткое описание о том, как ищутся сборке в
   каталоге приложения (для закрытого развёртывания).
2. Подключиться отладчиком. Если вам это не нужно - можно отключить в
   свойствах проекта (закладка Build - Advanced) для release режима.
   Подробно можно почитать на английском:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/5457250/5752652 или у того же Рихтера.
3. Сильно зависит от того, что это за xml-файлы. Конкретные примеры?

Comment: За конкретную отсылку на книгу и статью огромное спасибо! На досуге ознакомлюсь.

Например, последний проект писался с использованием паттерна MVVM, использовал библиотеку MvvmLight, а она компилит в релизную папку файл GalaSoft.MvvmLight.xml

Comment: в 2 - еще и отладка дампов. мало ли что бывает.

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо!
Только сейчас заметил, что не поблагодарил!

Answer (score 4):

1. Никак. Не надо ничего раскладывать по отдельным папкам, если это не вызвано какой-то реальной необходимостью (например, механизм загрузки ресурсов может искать сборки в папках с именами ru-ru и en-us).
2. Нужны для отладки релизной сборки. В окончательный инсталлер их можно не включать, но если есть хоть какая-то вероятность отладки релиза, хотя бы на стадии предрелизного тестирования - стоит сохранить копию pdb. MS есть [отдельный "сервер" для хранения символов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms680693(v=vs.85).aspx) - набор утилит для организации хранения pdb.
3. XML документация - файлы с именами someassembly.xml - не нужны, кроме случая, когда ваш продукт - это именно сама сборка. Все остальное - зависит от того, что это за файлы. XML - это просто формат, в файле может лежать что угодно, так что в общем виде заранее оценить его необходимость невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
А в ситуациях когда мне все таки потребуется внести дополнительные папки, например, для той же локализации? Как указать программе где искать файлы?

Comment: @UporotayaPanda в такой ситуации у вас уже будут эти папки, как при сборке релиза, так и при сборке обычной отладочной копии. Вообще структура папок - на усмотрение разработчика. Если вам очень хочется перенести что-то конкретное в отдельную папку и вы точно знаете как это сделать - переносите. Если не знаете - лучше не тратьте на это время :) Например, переносить dll-ки, на которые вы ссылаетесь - это, обычно, плохая идея, т.к. ничего, кроме "красивой" раскладки папок, не дает.

Comment: Можете поделиться мнением как пользователи реагируют, когда в папке .dll не структурированы? Мой путь в программировании еще не столь велик, и фидбэка насчет этого я еще не получал...

Comment: @UporotayaPanda Господи, да пользователи вообще не обращают внимания на это....

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Обычные пользователи не заглядывают в каталог с программой никогда. Программисты изредка заглядывают, но их среди ваших пользователей с хорошей точностью 0%.

Comment: @VladD рад вас видеть!) Добрый день!)

В моем случае оказалось, что начальник департамента охраны, для которых мы делали софт, не найдя ярлык на рабочем столе, полез в папку. А потом долго ругался, почему это в папке с WOT куда он закидывает моды все красиво разложено, а у нас все в перемешку...)

Comment: @UporotayaPanda Извините, но ваш начальник департамента охраны некомпетентен в разработке. Вы можете его выслушать, но не обязаны хоть как-то реагировать на его "рекоммендации". Очень простой принцип - вы не даете ему советов по охране, он не дает вам советов по раскладыванию файлов. Если ему больше нравится раскладка файлов WOT - пусть пользуется WOT вместо вашего софта, всего делов-то.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Присоединяюсь к предыдущему оратору, пусть начальник охраны наводит порядок на своём рабочем месте. Потому что раскладка файлов по папкам во-первых, геморрой, который может многое сломать, а во-вторых, никому не нужна в реальности. А вот отсутствие ярлыка на рабочем столе — прокол, не нужно заставлять юзера знать, где и как располагается ваша программа.